# Cierre de sesión con servlets JAVA

Tags: java, servlets, session

Tengo un problema con el cierre de sesión,he leído que debo utilizar el método `.invalidate()` en la sesión creada, pero hago eso, y la próxima vez que entro al `login`, me sigue comparando con los datos del anterior usuario, en otras palabras, no borra los atributos de sesión creados anteriormente.

Lo tengo implementado de la siguiente manera:iniciar:
En el `dopost` de un `servlet` llamado `login` la creo

```
HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
```

y le agrego varios atributos, al Finalizar en otro servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
    sesion.invalidate();
    response.sendRedirect("/index.jsp");
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código relevante de cómo creas y cómo destruyes la sesión? [ask]. [mcve]

Comment: Por favor no añadas el código en los comentarios. Edita la pregunta y añádelo allí.

Comment: Si, gracias,disculpa es que soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: ¿Qué clase de autenticación usas (el navegador puede cachear la autenticación BASIC)? ¿Estás seguro de que es la misma sesión y no una nueva (comprueba si la sesión tiene atributos asignados)?

Comment: Eh no tengo casi conocimientos de eso de autenticación, pero si tenia esa duda, que ¿si al declarar una sesion otra vez, es la misma?
Puede ser ese el problema.

Answer (score 1):

```
RequestDispatcher rd = null;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    String accion = "";
    accion = request.getParameter("uAccion");


    switch(accion){
        case "Salir":
            session.invalidate();
            request.setAttribute("message", "Sesión finalizada.");
            siguientePag = "/index.jsp";
   }
```

Ahi tienes lo que uso yo en mi proyecto. Con session.invalidate(); Matas la sesion, y luego rediriges al index.

EDIT: no habia leido, al hacer el login, tienes que cargar los datos del usuairio nuevo en la sesion.

```
session.setAttribute("usuario", "pepito");
```